# Python pandas column operations

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to do some columnar operations on a dataframe and I'm stuck at one point. I'm new to pandas and now I'm unable to figure how to do this.

So wherever there is a "Yes" value in "Prevous_Line_Has_Br" buffer should be added to the "OldTop" value but whenever there is a "No" in between it should stop incrementing, take the previous row value and start incrementing when there is a "Yes" again.

I have tried something like this

```
            temp_df["CheckBr"] = temp_df["Prevous_Line_Has_Br"].shift(1)
            temp_df["CheckBr"] = temp_df["CheckBr"].fillna("dummy")
            temp_df.insert(0, 'New_ID', range(0, 0 + len(temp_df)))
            temp_df["NewTop"] = "NoIncr"
            temp_df["MyTop"] = 0

            temp_df.loc[(temp_df["Prevous_Line_Has_Br"] == "Yes") & (temp_df["CheckBr"] == "Yes"), "NewTop"] = "Incr"
            temp_df.loc[(temp_df["Prevous_Line_Has_Br"] == "Yes") & (temp_df["CheckBr"] == "No"), "NewTop"] = "Incr"
            temp_df.loc[(temp_df["Prevous_Line_Has_Br"] == "Yes") & (temp_df["CheckBr"] == "dummy"), "NewTop"] = "Incr"


            temp_df.loc[(temp_df["NewTop"]=="Incr"),"MyTop" ] = new_top + (temp_df.New_ID * temp_df.buffer)
            temp_df.loc[(temp_df["CheckBr"] == "Yes") & (temp_df["MyTop"] == 0), "MyTop"] = temp_df["MyTop"].shift(1)
```

This is giving me the following output to achieve the same without the for loop:
[image: Modified dataframe]

Can someone please help achieve the values in the original dataframe using pandas?

This is what I want to achieve finally..
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I achieved the output I desired

```
            m = temp_df['Prevous_Line_Has_Br'].eq('Yes')

            temp_df['New_ID'] = m.cumsum().where(m,np.nan)

            temp_df["New_ID"] = temp_df["New_ID"].ffill()

            temp_df["Top"] = temp_df['Old_Top'] + (temp_df['New_ID'] * temp_df['buffer'])
```

Column `New_ID` was incremented only when there was a value `'Yes'` in column `Previous_Line_Has_br`.

Answer (score 0):

This would be fairly easy to do if you moved away from pandas, and treated the columns as just lists. If you want to still use the apply method, you can use to decorator to keep track of the last row.

```
def apply_func_decorator(func):
    prev_row = {}
    def wrapper(curr_row, **kwargs):
        val = func(curr_row, prev_row)
        prev_row.update(curr_row)
        prev_row[new_col] = val
        return val
    return wrapper

@apply_func_decorator
def add_buffer_and_top(curr_row, prev_row):
    if curr_row.Prevous_Line_Has_Br == 'Yes':
        if prev_row:
            return curr_row.buffer + prev_row['NewTop']
        return curr_row.buffer + prev_row['OldTop']
    return prev_row['NewTop']

temp_df['NewTop'] = 0
temp_df['NewTop'] = temp_df.apply(add_buffer_and_top, axis=1)
```

Comment: What is the new_col in prev_row[new_col] = val line? If you could please explain @ATIF ADIB

Comment: It'll be the previous NewTop value

Comment: Applying this solution gives me the buffer value in the NewTop column wherever it is required but my problem is not figuring that out. My problem is to break that buffer increment when there is a No. It should continue incrementing taking the previous row's Top value when there is a Yes again..  @ATIF ADIB  any idea how to do this?